# Arrays in Textboxes

Tags: java

I am making a user password database to be written onto a file. I have tried experimenting with the string array username, but it still renders like the same with a regular string; the output prints whatever you entered last in the second line of the file (the first being Username, Email...)

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    openFile();
    addRecords();
    closeFile();
}

public void addRecords(){
    int records = Integer.parseInt(textField_4.getText());
    x.format("%-25s %-25s %-25s %-25s \n", "Username", "Email", "Mojang Password", "Email Password");
    String username[] = new String[records];
    for(int counter = 0; counter<records; counter++){
        username[counter] = textField.getText();
        textField.setText("");
        String email = textField_1.getText();
        String userpass = textField_2.getText();
        String emailpass = textField_3.getText();
        x.format("%-25s %-25s %-25s %-25s \n", username[counter], email, userpass, emailpass);  
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Maybe could give us the output you are currently receiving and which output you would like to receive ?

Comment: You're not assigning the result of x.format to anything

Comment: what I am supposed to receive but I what I receive:http://pastebin.com/qXhmqxDb

Answer (score 1):

The way you are storing the data needs to be changed. Each record should be like this

```
record[0] - {username,email,userpass,emailpass} -  for user 1
record[1] - {username,email,userpass,emailpass} -  for user 2
```

save it as

```
for user1 - 
record[0][0] = username
record[0][1] = email 
record[0][2] = userpass 
record[0][3] = emailpass

for user2 - 

record[1][0] = username
record[1][1] = email 
record[1][2] = userpass 
record[1][3] = emailpass
```

and when you access it

```
for(int counter = 0; counter<records; counter++){
        username = record[counter][0];
        String email = record[counter][1];
        String userpass = record[counter][2];
        String emailpass = record[counter][3];
        x.format("%-25s %-25s %-25s %-25s \n", username, email, userpass, emailpass);  
    }
```